# Save generated excel instead of downloading

Tags: php, save, export-to-excel

The goal is to map the data in a table from a database to an excel file. The code is able to do that but I want to run some scripts post this and download it later. But it downloads when this page loads.Is there a way to save the excel file exported from mysql database instead of downloading it? code below:-

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

$DB_Server = "localhost"; //MySQL Server    
$DB_Username = "xxxx"; //MySQL Username     
$DB_Password = "xxxx";             //MySQL Password     
$DB_DBName = "xxxx";         //MySQL Database Name  
$DB_TBLName = "xxxx"; //MySQL Table Name   
$filename = "output";         //File Name



//create MySQL connection  
$Connect = mysqli_connect($DB_Server, $DB_Username, $DB_Password, $DB_DBName) or die("Couldn't connect to MySQL:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());



//execute query 
$sql = "Select * from $DB_TBLName";
$result = mysqli_query($Connect,$sql) or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());

$file_ending = "xls";

//header info for browser
header("Content-Type: application/xls");  
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");



for ($i=0;$i<=13;$i++)
{
    $column_name[$i] = $result->fetch_field_direct($i);
    echo $column_name[$i]->name."\t";

}

print("\n");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))

    {

        $schema_insert = "";

        for($j=0; $j<14;$j++)

      {

            if(!isset($row[$j]))

                $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;

           elseif ($row[$j] != "")

                $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;

            else

                $schema_insert .= "".$sep;

        }

        $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);

    $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);

        $schema_insert .= "\t";

        print(trim($schema_insert));

        print "\n";

    }



?>
```

Comment: Why not write the file to the disc using fwrite()? Also look at http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Comment: Checked the example posted.. Replaced a few lines.. Works for excel too.. Thanks a lot Erin

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work more with Excel files then maybe you should take a look at PHPExcel. It hasn't the cleanest PHP but works pretty fine.

Working with your code, you can use the function file_put_contents or SplFileObject class.

Answer (score 0):

The headers you send may be forcing the browser to download the response as a file. You may consider saving the results to disk behind the scene and then redirecting the page to somewhere else.